# Xcode 11 not released simultaneously with iOS 13?

Tags: ios, xcode

Yesterday I installed the public release iOS 13 on my development iPhone, assuming that Xcode 11 was released as well.

This morning, I wanted to install the latest Xcode, only to find out that it was not released yet! So right now I cannot compile/test on my iOS 13 device (without switching over to Xcode beta).

I cannot remember that this has happened in the past. Again, I'm not interested in switching to Xcode beta/GM on this machine, as I'm in production environment. Does anyone has any insights on when Xcode 11 public release will be available? Was there ever a delay in Xcode release after public iOS release?

Comment: Possibly next month.

Comment: Any sources for that? Is that assuming that it will only release together with macOS Catalina? As far as I know Xcode 11 will also be compatible with Mojave.

Comment: GM is as good as the release. You can install it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Public Xcode may come out later on Sept. 30th together with iPadOS (not confirmed ofc) since devs have a GM Seed 2 already and it seems to be pretty stable. So that’s my guess..

**Edit:** Xcode 11 was released for the Mac AppStore one day after iOS 13, on Sept. 20th 2019

To the second part, about previous releases:

- (2018) iOS 11: September 17; Xcode 9.0: September 12
- (2014) iOS 8: September 17; Xcode 6.0: September 09
- (2013) iOS 7: September 18; Xcode 5.0: September 16

However, you’re right in recent years Apple mostly released iOS and Xcode at the same time.. so it shouldn’t take too long.

Hope this was helpful :)

Comment: Actually GM seed 2 release notes say `Xcode 11 is available in the Mac App Store...`. So they are probably slacking. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_release_notes/

Comment: Thanks! Also I just noticed GM 2 also can be used to submit apps to the store if you have to. Too bad now we've got to go through the hassle of installing a separately downloaded Xcode instead of a simple Mac App Store update.

Comment: @Desdenova yes good spot; I've read that too, it was confusing! They must have had some unusual delay at Apple, it might be the delayed iPadOS release as thisIsTheFoxe said.

Comment: Maybe. We'll see in four days since iPadOS will go public at 24.9

Comment: @Rob yep, that was sooner some expected!